# Seriously? Programming?

Tags: bug, close-reasons

So I took a look at guidance on closed questions

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

and it says:

> This question does not appear to be about programming...

Um, seriously? programming?

Comment: Looks like that's the only word that needs fixing on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for noticing this and letting us know about this!

The short explanation:
The quoted close texts on the help page you've pointed out are intended to be representative reasons and explanations, not strictly necessarily those that are seen on the specific site you're on.

Why not just use the actual texts for our site?

Because many of the pages in the Help Center, while appearing to be specific to the site shown in their URLs, are in fact generic pages that are the same for all sites across all of Stack Exchange. While some of these pages *could* be made site-specific, in general it is best *not* to, as changing them locally prevents them from being updated when the site-wide versions are. This creates additional work for the moderators and, as in the example of the page you're commenting about, may only result in a change of a single word — probably not worth the extra overhead in manually maintaining that page forever more.

I appreciate you took the time to point out the oddity, but I think in this case it's better to retain the generic page. Most users who even notice will probably, like you, experience a brief "huh?" moment, understand what is *meant*, and will take from the page what they need.